# how to prevent jq from clicking recursively?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have pop up and select html list when user select 1st  item and save it to database but when user select 2nd and 3th item it will keep clicking the save button in the background.I don't know how to prevent it from clicking and I thing  it is because of loop?

html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h2 class="modal-title">Role Editor</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="error-field-role" class="has-error">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label"> Role:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <select id="ruleFields" class="form-control valid" data-bind="uniqueName: true, options: roleChoices, value: newRoleId, optionsText: &quot;name&quot;, optionsValue: &quot;recordId&quot;, optionsCaption: &quot;Choose...&quot;" name="ko_unique_1"><option value="">Choose...</option><option value="1">User</option><option value="2">Receiver</option><option value="3">Supervisor</option><option value="4">Administrator</option><option value="5">Privacy</option><option value="6">SystemConfigurator</option><option value="7">SystemAdministrator</option><option value="8">Quality</option><option value="9">QuickEvent</option><option value="10">test Roles</option><option value="11">ew1234</option><option value="12">test roles 123456</option><option value="13">fdssfdvsd</option><option value="14">yyyy</option><option value="15">222</option><option value="16">yttyjt</option><option value="17">77776</option><option value="18">99090</option><option value="19">fbdfb</option></select>
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="logo logo-required"></span>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>




                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveRole">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

JavaScript

```
 self.openInsertRoleDialog = function (event) {

        $("#add-role-dialog").modal("show");
        $("#saveRole").click(function (event) {
            event.isPropagationStopped();
            var save = true;
            var warning = "Please complete the following <hr/>";
            var role = $("#ruleFields").val();


            if (role == "") {
                save = false;
                warning = warning + 'You must select  a role' + '<br/>';
                $('#error-field-role').addClass("has-error");

            } else {

                $('#error-field-role').removeClass("has-error");
            }
            if (save) {
                self.insertRole();
                self.newRoleId('');
                $("#add-role-dialog").modal("hide");

            }
            else {
                toastr.warning(warning);
            }

        });
    };

    self.insertRole = function() {
        //make sure it's not already on the list
        //r Warning = "the Item is already on List" + '<hr/>';
        var alreadyOnList = false;
        $.each(self.selectedRule().rolesThatMustReview(), function(index, item) {
            if (item.RoleId === self.newRoleId()) {
                alreadyOnList = true;


                return false; //break
            } //if
        }); //each
        if (!alreadyOnList) {
            //resolve role name
            var roleName = '';
            $.each(self.roleChoices(), function(index, item) {
                if (item.recordId() === self.newRoleId()) {
                    roleName = item.name;
                    return false;//break
                }
            });
            self.selectedRule().rolesThatMustReview.push({
                RuleId: self.selectedRule().recordId(),
                RoleId: self.newRoleId(),
                RoleName: roleName,
                ShowNotification: false
            });//push

        }//if

    };
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with `event.isPropagationStopped();`, did you mean to use `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that every time you call openInsertRoleDialog a new click event is bound to $("#saveRole"), which means for every call to openInsertRoleDialog you will have n click bindings. This would explain the first click working and every other click saving more than once.

Instead of using .click, I suggest using .one

```
$("#saveRole").one('click', function () { your save code here })
```

Or, since I'm not sure if you still need the click event if a warning occurs you could unbind the click event on a successful save, as shown below.

```
if (save) {
     self.insertRole();
     self.newRoleId('');
     $('#saveRole').unbind('click');
     $("#add-role-dialog").modal("hide");
}
else {
     toastr.warning(warning);
}
```